# Get the index of the largest area in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

say I have the following array of arrays of area coordinates `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`. In my case, those coords describe the areas of detected faces in an image:

```
[
    [1, 1, 41, 41],
    [134, 13, 154, 33]
]
```

Now, I would like to get either an index of the largest area or the largest area itself. I know I can iterate over the array, compute the area of each entry and than sort to get the largest one. Standard loops in Python are super slow so I am looking for a NumPy solution that could speed things up (imagine there are 1MM individual areas in that array).

In the example above, I am looking to get an array index `0` or the area itself `[1, 1, 41, 41]` as it's the largest from the two (largest in terms of area, not coords themselves).

Comment: is this a case where simple aritmetics of array is sufficient? This is enough to calculate an area as `(a[2]-a[0]) * (a[3]-a[1])` for each item of your example and after that find index of maximum item. Since we are working with `numpy`, no iterations are needed.

Comment: Please don't downvote without explanation. Will be happy to address your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about limitations of memory but 1MM might be possible in a matter of >1 hour of computations if combining `numpy` with `numexpr`. `numexpr` is a good choice when arithmetics is simple. I have experimented with these options and found that `max` method is fastest on numpy but arithmetics is faster on `numexpr`:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
a = np.random.randint(10000000, size=(100000000, 4))
a[:,2] = a[:,0]+a[:,2]
a[:,3] = a[:,1]+a[:,3]
x,y,z,t = a[:,0], a[:,1], a[:,2], a[:,3]
%timeit np.max((z-x) * (t-y)) 
%timeit ne.evaluate('max((z-x) * (t-y))')
%timeit np.max(ne.evaluate('(z-x) * (t-y)'))
```

#### Output:

```
1.04 s ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
701 ms ± 2.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
330 ms ± 2.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In comparison, indices of `max` items can be found like so:

```
%timeit np.argmax((z-x) * (t-y)) 
%timeit np.argmax(ne.evaluate('(z-x) * (t-y)'))
```

#### Output:

```
1.02 s ± 17.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
317 ms ± 8.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```